# Dotfuscator community edition

Tags: .net, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I tried to use this on my class library "mylib.core.data.dll" and got a successful obfuscation, however, when I import this dll into another project via "Reference" and tried

imports --- My library "mylib.core.data.dll", doesn't show except for "e" and "h". Can someone tell me what I missed during the obfuscation process?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You properly obfuscated the file and your classes were renamed.  If your dll is going to be a library dotfuscator has a library mode you can set or you can turn off renaming.

Comment: You are correct it worked. I also found that you can actually specify a "namespace" from the "Rename" tab.